# .RData error - R doesn't load

Tags: r

R won't load throwing the following error:

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded 
In addition: Warning message: file ‘.RData’ has magic number ''   
Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

How might I resolve this error?

Comment: You can move the `.Rdata` file to a different location, and then RStudio will start. It is normally in your work directory or home folder (might be a hidden file)

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks! :)

Comment: Rstudio is just an IDE. Unless you can provide information this is RStudio specific, this is an R issue alone. Have you tried deleting the .RData? I suspect you're trying to restore a previous session.

Comment: @warmoverflow please consider adding your solution as answer so it can be accepted and address this problem for future readers as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `.RData` file is corrupt. Try removing or renaming it, i.e.

```
rm .RData
```

or

```
mv .RData _RData
```